# Xcode 11 unable to CopyPlistFile plist file that was just copied using build phase

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, plist, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://medium.com/bam-tech/setup-firebase-on-ios-android-with-multiple-environments-ad4e7ef35607) (for iOS) for setting up multiple environments for my React Native project. The idea is that I can make use of Build Phases to copy any plist into GoogleService-Info.plist to enable the use of different Firebase environments for different Xcode schemes.

I've made a user-defined build setting for each of my 4 Xcode configurations called `GOOGLE_SERVICE_PLIST_SUFFIX`, and I have a build phase (it's the first one that's run before React native Copies and Bundles its required assets) with the following code:

```
cp -r "GoogleService-Info"$GOOGLE_SERVICE_PLIST_SUFFIX".plist" "GoogleService-Info.plist" &
wait $!
echo "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_PLIST_SUFFIX} Firebase plist copied"
```

I can tell that the copying is indeed successful, but for some reason the build fails with this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CopyPlistFile /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/build/biteup/Build/Products/Prod.Debug-iphonesimulator/Myappname.app/GoogleService-Info.plist /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist
(1 failure)
```

Looking at the error trace, this error is explained a bit further:

```
CopyPlistFile /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/build/myappname/Build/Products/Prod.Debug-iphonesimulator/Myappname.app/GoogleService-Info.plist /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist (in target 'myappname' from project 'myappname')
    cd /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios
    builtin-copyPlist --convert binary1 --outdir /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/build/myappname/Build/Products/Prod.Debug-iphonesimulator/Biteup.app -- /Users/andersonaddo/myappname/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/andersonaddo/lunchme/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'biteup' from project 'biteup')
```

Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour may be happening? If i try and build again after the first failure, I don't run into this issue because the copied file remains in the `ios` directory from the first attempt.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I ended up making a bash script that copied the correct plist file to the project before building and deletes that file after building

Comment: Ah fair play, I have just got mine working (with a slightly different guide) but a similar concept. Instead, this just copies the plist file into the target on build rather than deletions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved a similar outcome to what you are after by using schemes and a build script against each scheme.

I used an approach similar to what's details here to set up alpha (dev), beta (stage) and prod builds:
https://blog.echobind.com/a-12-factor-approach-to-environment-specific-builds-in-react-native-ae1fb77ed799

Then I set up the 3 apps in Firebase and saved the plist files in my app with relevant names (eg GoogleService-Info-beta.plist).

Lastly, I added to the run script for each scheme (as below) and it works great.

RN @ 0.62.2, RNFB @ v7.1.0

[image: Scheme run script]

I've added the file that gets copied to (GoogleService-Info.plist) to my gitignore as it obv changes when I run diff schemes on my machine